# InstaWeather app on iOS wanted

Tags: ios, iphone-app, weather

On Android I had the app called InstaWeather. It was about creating an overlay of the weather situation on a photo. See example. Is there a similar app für iOS? Instagram support is not a must, I just want the overlay to be created automatically.

[image]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Price limit would be EUR 5 if it comes to paid apps.

Comment: Must it be [tag:gratis] – or what is your price limit if it comes to paid solutions? (und: Willkommen aus Schwabing ;)

Comment: My limit is 5 EUR. Greetings from Sendling.

Comment: Thanks! I've integrated that with your question, and will cleanup the (now obsolete) comments soon. Greetings to my (currently deserted) workplace from my home-office :D